# iphone: how to get previous popped up view controller from UINavigation Controller?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I want to do customized setting for a view according to the previous view which just popup.
So I want to know who is just popup programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once any thing is poped u loose access to that object so what u can do is that u can take a variable in appDelegate and update it before poping any viewController,by this you can track which viewController is poped recent.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea to save the poped controller in a shared object. Thank you.

Comment: Please avoid storing the whole controller ....... infact you can make an enum in ur appDlegate and a variable to track the poped controller, just update that variable to keep track of what u wanted